# Qt QModelIndex::sibling return parent QModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

Having a QAbstractItemModel `grModel` and calling:

```
QModelIndex grSrcPrtIdx = grModel.index( 1, 0 );
QModelIndex grSrcIdx1   = grSrcPrtIdx.sibling( 1, 0 );
QModelIndex grSrcIdx2   = grModel.index( 1, 0, grSrcPrtIdx )
```

Results in: `grSrcPrtIdx == grSrcIdx1` with `grSrcPrtIdx` containing the data expected for `grSrcPrtIdx` while `grSrcIdx2` contains the expected data for the sibling. My expectation is that `grSrcIdx1 == grSrcIdx2`.

It seems that the sibling function provides a defaut implementation (or something similar?).

What might be the cause that the sibiling function does not deliver the siblings `QModelIndex`? Did I miss to implement a function of the `QAbstractItemModel`?

Qt version used is Qt 5.10.0 (MinGw).

Comment: I think you're just confusing [`sibling index`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#sibling) with [`child index`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index)?  If two `QModelIndex`s are siblings then they have the same parent.  What you are seeing is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: The sibling function returns the model index for an item on the same level as the index for which it was called. In your case you are attempting to get a sibling of grSrcPrtIdx at row 1, column 0, and as it happens grSrcPrtIdx is at row 1, column 0 and so it's returning the same value again.

Comment: Ok, sorry for mixing up the translations & many thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments of G.M. and aatwo are the helping ones.